# Eventlets and SMTP

Tags: python, django, smtplib, eventlet

I would like to multithread sending mail (using django's SMTPConnection or perhaps the smtplib module).  I was hoping there was a module similar to urllib2 where I can:

```
import eventlet
from eventlet.green import urllib2
```

except using smtplib instead of the urllib2 import.  However, this does to appear to supported.  I read this could monkey patched(?), but I am unsure how to proceed.  Any ideas how this can be accomplished with eventlets?  Or do I have to drop down into the python Thread class, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
import module
```

Or

```
module = eventlet.import_patched(module)
```

Either should work for you.

http://eventlet.net/doc/patching.html